# WinAPI: repeatable check in a separate thread that notifies UI thread when check fails

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mfc, c++03

My application has a separate thread that repeatably performs some check. If the check fails, the UI thread is notified (a MessageBox is displayed that requires user action what to do next).

Unfortunately, I have to use **C++03** compiler (Visual Studio 2010 SP1) and **boost** library usage is prohibited. Therefore, I cannot use `<thread>`, `<atomic>`, `<chrono>`, etc. Thats why I have to use  `CreateThread`, `PostMessage` and other WinAPI functions.

Here is my UI thread code (simplified). My main window is [CMDIFrameWnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmdiframewnd-class?view=msvc-140) (from MFC):

```
//a struct with all parameters that is needed for a repeatable check
struct RepeatFunctionParameters
{
    unsigned int repeatDelayInMilliseconds;
    HWND checkIsFailedPostMessageWindowHandler;
    UINT checkIsFailedPostMessageMessageId;
    HANDLE checkIsPausedMutexHandle;

    RepeatFunctionParameters(unsigned int _repeatDelayInMilliseconds, HWND _checkIsFailedPostMessageWindowHandler,
        UINT _checkIsFailedPostMessageMessageId, HANDLE _haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle)
        : repeatDelayInMilliseconds(_repeatDelayInMilliseconds), checkIsFailedPostMessageWindowHandler(_checkIsFailedPostMessageWindowHandler),
        checkIsFailedPostMessageMessageId(_checkIsFailedPostMessageMessageId), haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle(_haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle)
    {}
};

----------------------------
//creating a mutex to pause repeatable checks (whe Messagebox is displayed in UI thread)
HANDLE haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

//starting a separate thread with a check that repeats every 5000 milliseconds
auto params = new RepeatFunctionParameters(5000, myApp_hWnd, WM_USER_HASP_CHECK_FAILED, haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle);
CreateThread(NULL, 0, RepeatFunction, params, 0, NULL);

----------------------------
//special message that is sended when check is failed
#define WM_USER_HASP_CHECK_FAILED              (WM_USER+0x150)

//mapping message handling function to that message
ON_MESSAGE( WM_USER_HASP_CHECK_FAILED, OnUserHaspCheckFailed)

//message handling function definition
afx_msg LRESULT OnUserHaspCheckFailed(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

//message handling function body 
LRESULT CMainWnd::OnUserHaspCheckFailed(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //capturing a mutex that signals to pause repeatable checks
    WaitForSingleObject(haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle, INFINITE);
    
    //show a messagebox that requires user action what to do next
    if (::MessageBox(myApp_hWnd, ("Check is failed! Retry or cancel?").c_str(),
            myApp_name, MB_RETRYCANCEL | MB_ICONERROR | MB_SYSTEMMODAL) == IDCANCEL)
            //closing main windows if user clicks Cancel
            pWnd->SendMessage(WM_CLOSE, 0x00010000, 0);

    //releasing a mutex that signals to pause repeatable checks
    ReleaseMutex(haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle);

    return 0;
}

//WM_CLOSE handling function body
LRESULT CMainWnd::OnClose( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ----------------------------

    if( haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle != NULL)
        CloseHandle( haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle);

    ----------------------------
    
    CMDIFrameWnd::OnClose();
    return NULL;
}
```

Here is my separate thread with repeatable check code (simplified):

```
DWORD WINAPI RepeatFunction(LPVOID parameters)
{
    //getting parameters struct from a pointer
    auto temp = static_cast<RepeatFunctionParameters*>(parameters);
    //make a struct local copy (Further, all work goes only with it, regardless of the 
    state of the object, the pointer to which came as a function parameter)
    auto params = *temp;
    //deleting the structure, the pointer to which came as a function parameter
    delete temp;

    //repeatable check
    while (true)
    {
        //checking a mutex that signals to pause repeatable checks. if it is free
        //then there is no messagebox in UI thread and we can perform a check.
        //if it is captured - wait until user clicks some button in that messagebox 
        WaitForSingleObject(params.haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle, INFINITE);
        //and releasing it immediately
        ReleaseMutex(params.haspSerialCheckIsPausedMutexHandle);

        auto startMilliseconds = GetTickCount();    
        //performing a check
        BOOL success = PerformACheck();

        unsigned long defaultSleepDelay = 1000;
        //if PerformACheck() will last longer than params.repeatDelayInMilliseconds,
        //then check will be repeated after 1000 milliseconds, otherwise - 
        //after params.repeatDelayInMilliseconds minus PerformACheck() call time
        auto endMilliseconds = GetTickCount();
        if ((endMilliseconds - startMilliseconds) < params.repeatDelayInMilliseconds)
            sleepDelay = params.repeatDelayInMilliseconds - (endMilliseconds - startMilliseconds);

        //if check is failed
        if (!success)
        {
            //sending a message with an identifier params.checkIsFailedPostMessageMessageId
            //to a HWND params.checkIsFailedPostMessageWindowHandler so in it's 
            //handling function a messagebox with will be displayed and a mutex 
            //params.haspSerialCheckCanRunMutexHandle will be captured until
            //user click some button in that messagebox 
            PostMessage(params.checkIsFailedPostMessageWindowHandler, params.checkIsFailedPostMessageMessageId, 0, 0);

            //if check is failed then next check always repeats after 1000 milliseconds
            sleepDelay = 1000;
        }

        Sleep(sleepDelay);
    }
}
```

The result is that the main window becomes unresponsive after some time. It looks like my code has some logical mistake, or a memory leak.

I'm a newbie to C++ (and especially to outdated standards).

Comment: Why don't you use SendMessage instead and get rid of the mutex (PS: a mutex is Windows is not equivalent to a std:mutex, it's usually more for cross-process synchronization). Or SendMessageTimeout to check if the window's dead or abnormally long to process.

Comment: @SimonMourier `SendMessage` will send a message and wait until `OnUserHaspCheckFailed` function will finish and return? I just need to change single line (`PostMessage` to `SendMessage`) and get rid of mutex? Or I need to change something else (code that map message handling function to message or function definition/body)?

Comment: SendMessage does not return until the window procedure has processed the message, which is what you seem to want to achieve with your mutex. And you won't get any possible race condition. I can't try since this is not a fully reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, that is exactly what I want to achieve with my mutex. Ok, I will try to make 2 changes (change `PostMessage` to `SendMessage` and get rid of mutex) and compile my code. I will notify about the debug results.